# x86 Irvine Assembly jmp + cmp and conditional loops - craps game

Tags: assembly, x86

Assembly is a fun language to learn. I still have a lot of room for improvement. I'm trying to make a simple craps game that should make random dice rolls x number of times based on user input. I have the code as follows:

```
TITLE Program Template          (main.asm)

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data
diceOne                     DWORD ? 
diceTwo                     DWORD ?
win                         DWORD 7, 11
lose                        DWORD 2, 3, 12
mark                        DWORD 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10
markCounter                 DWORD ?
userInput                   BYTE 'Enter integer: ', 0
numRolls                    DWORD ?
printWon                    BYTE 'Won: ', 0
wonCounter                  DWORD ?
printWin                    BYTE ' You win!', 0
printLost                   BYTE 'Lost: ', 0
lostCounter                 DWORD ?
printLose                   BYTE ' You lose!', 0
printTotal                  BYTE 'Total: ', 0
space                       DWORD ' ', 0
printPlus                   BYTE ' + ', 0
printMark                   BYTE ' Mark ', 0

.code
main PROC
    call randomize                      ; set random seed
    mov ecx, 6                          ; counter set to 6
    mov edx, offset userInput           ; print string
    call writeString
    call readInt                        ; read input
    mov numRolls, eax                   ; store input in variable
    mov ecx, numRolls                   
    mov eax, 0
    mov edi, offset win

    call gamesRolled

    exit
main ENDP
;number of games rolled based on user input
gamesRolled PROC uses eax ecx

DICEROLLS: 
    call crlf
                                ;diceOne roll
    mov eax, 5                  ;move value into eax to pass as parameter for randomrange
    call randomRange            ;randomrange stored in eax 0-5
    inc eax
    mov diceOne, eax            ;mov the value of randomrange into variable
    call writeDec       
    push edx                    ;push edx off stack to print space 
    mov edx, OFFSET printPlus
    call writeString
    pop edx
                                ;diceTwo roll
    mov eax, 6
    call randomRange
    inc eax
    mov diceTwo, eax
    call writeDec


    add eax, diceOne            ; add diceOne roll to diceTwo roll
    cmp eax, win                ; comp eax value to win
    je wins
    cmp eax, lose
    je losses
    cmp eax, mark
    je marks
    LOOP DICEROLLS

    ret
gamesRolled ENDP

wins PROC uses edi ecx
    mov edi, offset win
    mov ecx, lengthof win
    cmp eax, [edi]
    add edi, type win
    push edx
    mov edx, offset printWin
    call writeString
    pop edx
    jmp gamesRolled
    ret

wins ENDP

losses PROC uses edi ecx
    mov edi, offset lose
    mov ecx, lengthof lose
    cmp eax, [edi]
    add edi, type lose
    push edx
    mov edx, offset printLose
    call writeString
    pop edx
    jmp gamesRolled
    ret
losses ENDP

marks PROC uses edi ecx
    mov edi, offset lose
    mov ecx, lengthof lose
    cmp eax, [edi]
    add edi, type lose

    push edx
    mov edx, offset printMark
    call writeString    
    pop edx
    jmp gamesRolled
    ret
marks ENDP

END main
```

So it seems simple enough from the examples and explanations I have seen. I'm using the `cmp`/`je` to work like an if statement while I'm looping the dice rolls. The idea is to have the wins or loss or marks increase and print it all out. It works fine without the `cmp`/`je` part. I'm able to print random dice rolls, however, once I start trying to `cmp`/`je` I get some weird freezing and sometimes crashing. I'm trying to learn how to code better in assembly. Would you please help me understand why this isn't working the way I thought it should. I figured if I compare the `eax` register which contains the combined total of `diceOne + diceTwo` than it should jump to the other functions and in those functions `edi` should be like a counter that tallies while printing a string that indicates a win, lose, or mark. So for example:

```
Enter integer: 5
2 + 3 Mark
1 + 5 Mark
5 + 6 You win!
5 + 1 Mark
2 + 6 Mark
Wins: 1 Losses: 0 Marks: 4
```

I didn't get to the last part yet since I'm having trouble with the code as is. Appreciate any help with this. I'm at a loss.

This is an actual result I'm getting now:

```
Enter integer: 5

3 + 2
3 + 5
2 + 5 You win!
3 + 6
5 + 5
```

Comment: I know some of the variables are not in use, please ignore those.

Comment: i didnt understand the rule (tldr), but what I see you only compare against the values 7, 2 and 4, not to all of the array's members. is this intended ?

Comment: First `call randomRange` will produce values only in 0-4 range (`mov eax,5` ahead)

Comment: I don't see how your current version may get some freezing or crashing, it should do `ecx` many loops without any message, and show message win/lose/mark for values 7, 2, 4 (those throws with message don't count and can loop infinitely if only such throws are produced). Can you confirm what does the code you posted exactly? (I'm "running" it in my head only, so I may be wrong) ... oh.. indeed I am.. those message throws will also reset `ecx` to 2, 3 or 6, so it may loop way longer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your current version does:

First random call is 0-4 only.

`cmp eax, win`: You use MASM syntax, so this is `cmp eax,[mem32]` in Intel syntax, will compare `eax` against value `7` from `win` "array". Then `je wins` will jump for result 7 at code at `wins:` and that one will do some useless pointer stuff, reset `ecx` to 2, display message and jump back to main roll loop.

Similarly for lose/mark "arrays", the first element (2 for lose, 4 for mark) is tested, and when equal, the lose/mark message is displayed, with some useless stuff, resetting `ecx` and jumping straight back to rolling.

Only for the other values (3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11 (and missing 12 due to random bug)) the `loop` is executed, down-counting in `ecx` the total loops.

You should easily see this behaviour in debugger (and even find out any discrepancy to my description, if I did some mistake in my head, as my "emulation" of CPU is a bit limited and only about ~2Hz in speed), if you single-step over instructions and examine machine state after each step. Programming in assembly without debugger is like trying to assemble robot blindfolded. You can, but it is like 100x more difficult, so invest heavily into learning how to use debugger effectively, before continuing with assembly learning.

---

Some advices about code:

Overall you are a bit complicating it, I would do this otherwise, I would define in data the table (instead of the `win/lose/mark` arrays):

```
;             2L  3L  4M  5M  6M  7W  8M  9M 10M 11W 12L
outcome BYTE   1,  1,  2,  2,  2,  0,  2,  2,  2,  0,  1
outcomeMsgs:
    DWORD  OFFSET printWin, OFFSET printLose, OFFSET printMark
totalScore DWORD 0, 0, 0    ; wins / losses / marks
```

Then in code after second throw is displayed and you have in `eax` the sum of throws, you can pick the outcome as this:

```
    ; decide what is the outcome of throws
    movzx   ebx,byte ptr [outcome + eax - 2]
      ; ebx = 0/1/2 = win/lose/mark
    ; display outcome message
    mov     edx,[outcomeMsgs + ebx*4]
    call    writeString
    ; add to total score
    inc     dword ptr [totalScore + ebx*4]
    ; do ecx-many rolls
    dec     ecx
    jnz     DICEROLLS
    ; ending sequence
    ; for example, display total losses
    mov     edx,OFFSET printLost
    call    writeString
    mov     eax,[totalScore+4]
    call    writeDec
    ret
```

Unfortunately if you wanted to exercise that `cmp` against values from `win/...` arrays, this is avoiding that completely, so of little educational value. You should probably separately try to write that array test just to get more skill... after you learn to use debugger first, so you can actually check, what the code is truly doing.

Comment: wow i'm gonna have to digest this for a bit, thank you so much. Unfortunately I'm running this in cmd prompt and don't get the luxury of debugger. I'll have to learn how to use this in visual studio, making that a priority now :). I realized after posting this that i wasn't comparing the entire array and I would need to either make a loop/counter to go through the array or I would just try to cmp eax, 7 / cmp eax, 11 and this seemed to work for the first roll, but than it would crash. I really need a tutor for this, unfortunately I can't find anyone who really knows this stuff anyway thank you

Comment: if you wouldn't mind, please explain how is this printing out the value of rolls lost
mov     eax,[totalScore+4]

Comment: @Alex Check my definition of `totalScore`.. it's 3x DWORD 0. So the first DWORD is at address `totalScore+0`, second is at `totalScore+4` and third at `totalScore+8`. Now in my example I increment those values by doing `inc     dword ptr [totalScore + ebx*4]` where ebx = 0/1/2 as win/lose/mark, so the losses are counted in memory at address `totalScore+4` (as DWORD, 4 bytes up to addres `totalScore+7` are affected). ... Visual Studio is able to debug also console executables.